# Get SSH port forwarding information on SSH server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have a server that provides external clients with access/tunneling to internal hosts. For example clients can port forward to specific ports on the internal host via the following SSH command:

```
ssh -i some_cert 5500:192.168.0.1:5500 user@hostserver
```

Clients are port forwarding their port 5500 to host 192.168.0.1's port 5500, where 192.168.0.1 is the address relative to hostserver. This process works fine, however is there a way to determine (on the server) which SSH process are responsible for tunnelling to a given internal host/port. Running ps aux just gives me the sshd processes but what would be the best way to correlate the sshd process to the internal host the connection is being tunnelled to?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sudo ss -tupln | grep sshd` to see all open ports by sshd
Combine it with the process id's and you get the information